# How to create a Web Application from scratch using BDD?

Tags: testing, web-applications, tdd, bdd

I want to start a pet project to get confident with creating Web Applications from scratch and I want to use BDD and TDD.
I read in "Growing Object-Oriented Software: Guided by Tests" that we should start from the thinnest slice of the system that allows us to have a walking skeleton of the entire application so we have can have a quick feedback and start wondering about the production/deployment procedures.

After writing the acceptance test in BDD I would move to finer granularity tests such as Unit tests.

Imagining that the web application is about finding the superhero who is more similar to you, I would write a BDD scenario such as:

```
When I insert my information
Then the system should tell that the superhero I'm more similar to is "Batman"
```

I'm ignoring the authentication on purpose so we can focus on the main functionality of the system. This scenario assumes that there is a working infrastructure behind, so that the scenario above can be replicated automatically, end-to-end.

Assuming that I want to lay out the web application in different layers (Web Server, Application Server and Database), how can I implement this test?
Supposing I want to use Selenium WebDriver to simulate the user, what layers must be mocked and what layer is going to be tested first?
I also thought about starting from testing the API only, but that wouldn't be a end-to-end test, but we would test the application only partially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber is a good framework for BDD. UI/Selenium tests can be a bit flakey so I would suggest less of them (see Testing Pyramid).
Personally I think I would work at the API level as you suggested for starters, then you have decoupled the UI from the app.

Write some Cucumber Integration Tests of the Application (BDD) at the API level, describing high level features. I wouldn't mock at this level, as you want to see the whole app working at this point.

Then as you implement these, use TDD, here you will want to mock out externals like File IO/Database. Once all the TDD Unit Tests are done, the overall feature should then pass. Continue until all features are completed.

Continue like this and then you have a solid set of unit tests and a solid set of Integration (feature) tests at API level.

Once done (or in parallel to get a vertical slice) start the UI using 'happy day' scenario selenium tests, all that really needs testing here is the UI code and that is correctly hooked up to the App, as the main App will be well tested already.

Just my view - Hope it helps.

Comment: Would you use the same scenario above as API test?

Comment: Effectively yes. The API is tested using Integration and Unit Tests. Additional UI tests will also touch the the API if done at system level

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Cucumber for this (but I'm terribly biased), and I would start by writing some scenarios around the core part of your application.

Some important rules to follow when writing your scenarios

1. Use your domain language
2. Only talk about WHAT you are doing and WHY its important
3. Don't talk about HOW you do things.

So with your superhero site you can start with thinking about things you need to do to get started.

Generally when you have discovered a resource (superhero) you will have some basic CRUD operations you can explore, so

- creating superhero
- editing a superhero
- deleting a superhero
- COMPARING a superhero ** this is your key starting point **

Lets start working on the comparing a superhero scenario

`Given there are superheroes Batman and Superman
And I am like Batman
When I find my superhero
Then I should see I am like Batman`

Now lets start implementing this scenario. One important thing here is to not put all your code in your step definitions. Instead make each step definition a call to a helper method.

**note: all following code will be ruby**

`Given 'there are superheroes Batman and Superman' do
  create_superhero batman
  create_superhero superman
end`

And now we can get into the BDD red/green testing cycle.

So we will start getting errors like `No method found create_superhero` and `undefined constant batman`. We can address these with a helper module in our step definitions.

```
module CreateSuperHeroStepHelper
  def create_superhero(attrs={})
    Superhero.create(attrs)
  end

  def batman
    {
      ...
    }
  end

  ...

end
```

And from this code we can start working on the domain objects for our application e.g. Superhero.

To get this step working you'll have to interact with your underlying web framework. Once you have it working, in its most basic form you can move onto the next step.

Along the way you'll have all sorts of choices about what you do next. If you stick to working on this core scenario, you'll have to be clever about how you implement things. If you decide to work on scenarios that seem like pre-requisites e.g. user accounts, create superhero, enter your superhero characteristics, add a superhero characteristic. Then you should end up with tools which you can use for your core scenario (e.g. you'll have `create_superhero`) but it will take you longer to get to the core of your application.

There is no need to be thinking about unit tests, layers or mocking here. Thats low-level detail about HOW you do things which comes much later. So long as you have some basic competency in your web framework you should be to start exploring your domain and use  BDD to create simple tools that you can use to explore your World of superheroes.

Good luck

Comment: I got this and I really appreciate the answer, but my question is specifically about Web Applications, that is, from what layer the test should start from. I think it's a trade-off between the coverage of the test, its stability (as the end-to-end scenarios are a bit flakey) and the layers the test goes through.

Comment: the answer applies to web applications (its all I write nowadays). BDD is not about testing, its about discovering behaviour and driving development which means you have to do it way before you start thinking about coverage and implementation. When you are discovering behaviour you should start with the interaction (in scenarios the When). In web applications this is the interaction between a user and a browser (mostly). So your 'whens' should be using the browser. Your Givens can be more flexible and can bypass the browser as they are setting up state.